# Highlighting SI: "invalid-token-in-number"

Tags: siunitx, soul

I need to highlight some parts of code containing both text and numbers using the `siunitx`package but I get an `invalid-token-in-number`, the token being a number!

Here's my mwe:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{soul} % Enables highlighting
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

    %% Error: 
    %% siunitx error: "invalid-token-in-number" and "Invalid token '6' in numerical input."
        \hl{
        Dummy text to avoid SI as very first argument of hl
        \SI{666}{\nm}
        Dummy text just in case}


\end{document}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is a duplicate of the question just asked: use `{\SI{666}{\nm}}`

Comment: Although I see this answers the question, I can't rewrite all the instances of `\SI` in my text when it needs to be (temporarily) highlighted. I love LaTeX but <Troll_mode> what is the use of it if one needs to deeply understand its way of doing things, just to do a simple thing as highlighting physics text.</Troll_mode>

Comment: Also, it is not totally a duplicate since, in the other question, double braces can easily be added, since the `\hl{{\textcolor{white}{Fail}}}` is in fact a `\newcommand`with `Fail` being an argument that is passed along... which cannot be done in *this* question.

Comment: what `\hl` is doing can't remotely be described as simple:-) But you don't have to use it if you don't want you could use `\colorbox` to add the highlights or tikz or use Word.

Comment: @Maugan Highlighting is pretty rare in typeset documents, and actually achieving it in TeX is very complex as David alludes to.

Comment: It's not exactly a duplicate but you could repeat the question with any command taking arguments inside `\hl` the issue is totally unrelated to which command it is.

Comment: 1) I indeed tried `colorbox` but got confronted to line breaking problems. This is why `hl` seemed a nice replacement.^^

2) I might try `tikz`

and 3) As for using Word... could this be considered a Godwin point? :)

Comment: In simple cases `\colorbox{red}{\parbox{\textwidth}{......}}` is all you need.

Comment: Oh sweet baby J. didn't see that one (either "coming" or "when Googling for a way to do it"). So simple. Thanks!